# Why do Clearance guards check signed_in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clearance

Examples for Clearance guards all seem to check `signed_in?`. This is confusing to me because it seems like `signed_in?` should not be set to true until the user has passed the clearance guards. I thought the whole point of the guards was to prevent sign in.

```
class EmailConfirmationGuard < Clearance::SignInGuard
  def call
    if unconfirmed?
      failure("You must confirm your email address.")
    else
     next_guard
    end
  end

  def unconfirmed?
    signed_in? && !current_user.confirmed_at
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a reason why you would want to run the guard stack if the user is `nil`, so I'm not sure. I think it's likely an accident of implementation.

When creating a session we do this:

```
def create
  @user = authenticate(params)

  sign_in(@user) do |status|
    if status.success?
      redirect_back_or url_after_create
    else
      flash.now.notice = status.failure_message
      render template: "sessions/new", status: :unauthorized
    end
  end
end
```

If `authenticate` returns `nil`, we still enter the stack. We should probably consider not doing that. If you open an issue on the Clearance repository itself, we can consider it as a change for Clearance 2.0